# Problem using \begin{titlepage}

Tags: lyx, titles

I want to  make a front-page to something I've been writing in LyX but everytime I use `\begin{titlepage}\text {This is a sample title}\end{titlepage}`, I get in the first page this line only instead of real title:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you're planning on using the `titlepage` environment, you need to set it in a regular (or `Standard`) paragraph inside an ERT.

Comment: How can I do so?

Comment: Ctrl+L (or Insert > TeX Code) and type `\begin{titlepage} <your title> \end{titlepage}`.

Comment: thanks but:
a. my title is in hebrew and even after changing the encoding the document doesn't compile. 
b.How can I emphasize and centralize my title?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis Without an example of the LaTeX code written by LyX it's impossible to say something.

Comment: I know. I meant putting bounty on my with-code question (this one I've already solved) located here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134361/cannot-create-a-table-of-contents-in-lyx-for-a-hebrew-document .
I don't think I can move my bounty to the aforementioned question but if one answers it, I think that maybe if I accept it he'd answer here and I'd give him the bounty. As clumsy it seems to be that's my best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @scottsty suggested, I'd give my answer. I found out [this pdf](http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/~a0303098/public/lyx/memoir-titlepages.pdf) where there are many front-pages to choose from so now my latex code is

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\centering
\vspace*{0.08\textheight}
{\Huge\bfseries Assisting Material }\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Course}\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Lecturer:}\\[\baselineskip] 
{\large\scshape Prof. }\par
\vfill  {\plogo}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\scshape Concluded by Coargo,2013}\par 
\vspace*{0.16\textheight}  
\endgroup
```

which produces a well-dsigned front-page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example LyX file with a title page in Hebrew. (Just copy the following to a file and then open that file in LyX 2.0.x).

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass book
\begin_preamble
\frenchspacing
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mathdots 1
\use_mhchem 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 0
\index ××× ××§×¡
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language polish
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
××¨×××× ××××× ×- 
\lang english
LyX
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section*
××× × ×§××××ª ×©××©×× ×××¢×ª ×¢× ×©××××© ×- 
\lang english
LyX
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Note Note
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
×¢××¨××ª
\end_layout

\end_inset


\lang english
LyX
\lang hebrew
 ××××¢ ×¢× ××¡××× ×ª××¢×× ××¢××¨× ××¦×××× ×× 
\lang english
â
\lang hebrew
 ×××××¥ ×××©×ª××© ×××.
 ×××× ×××ª××× ××§×¨×××ª ××§×××¥ 
\family sans
×¢××¨×
\begin_inset Formula $\vartriangleleft$
\end_inset

××××
\family default
, ×××××× ××§××× ×§×¦×¨× ××ª××¢××.
 ××××¨ ×××, × ××ª× ××××©×× ××§×¨×××ª 
\family sans
×¢××¨×
\begin_inset Formula $\vartriangleleft$
\end_inset

××©××¢××¨
\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset

×××××¨×
\family default
 ×¢× ×× ×ª ××××× ××× ×××©×ª××© ×- 
\lang english
LyX
\lang hebrew
.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

And here is the resulting PDF on my system:

page 1:

[image: page 1]

page 2:

[image: page 2]

Finally, here is the `LaTeX` that is produced from that `.lyx` file:

```
%% LyX 2.0.7dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english,hebrew]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\frenchspacing

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{áøåëéí äáàéí ì- \inputencoding{latin9}\L{\LyX{}}}

\maketitle

\section*{ëîä ð÷åãåú ùçùåá ìãòú òì ùéîåù á- \L{\protect\LyX{}}}

\inputencoding{latin9}\L{\LyX{}}\inputencoding{cp1255} îâéò òí îñîëé
úéòåã åòæøä îöåééðéí \inputencoding{latin9}\L{\textemdash{}}\inputencoding{cp1255}
îåîìõ ìäùúîù áäí. ëãàé ìäúçéì á÷øéàú ä÷åáõ \textsf{òæøä\L{$\vartriangleleft$}îáåà},
äîäååä ä÷ãîä ÷öøä ìúéòåã. ìàçø îëï, ðéúï ìäîùéê á÷øéàú \textsf{òæøä\L{$\vartriangleleft$}äùéòåø~äîåãøê}
òì îðú ììîåã àéê ìäùúîù á- \inputencoding{latin9}\L{\LyX{}}\inputencoding{cp1255}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, thanks but look at my last comment. Can answer the 'correct' question too please ?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I don't understand. Do you mean the code that you use in the other thread? It doesn't use `\begin{titlepage}`. Also, I can't compile it. Do you have a minimal LyX example that compiles but just doesn't have the title page how you want?

Comment: I meant this thread I solved by myself but I wanted to offer bounty on the other (about the TOC), I added there a lyx file which  when I try to compile it, it shows example errors.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis OK. In that case, you should give an answer to your own question here and accept it.

Comment: Done. now, what will with the bounty? Can one answer my 'real' question and I'll give him the bounty from here?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I'm not sure how that works. Thank you for answering your question. This makes the question more self-contained in case someone has a similar question.

Comment: Thanks. Im still looking for solution to my urgent question. Can you plese look at it again please?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I don't have an idea for a solution. If you find one please post the answer there.

Comment: fine. I started bounty on the correct question now. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try compile these source files to get title page [Title Page Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages)