# Cannot create a table of contents in LyX for a Hebrew document

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm trying to create a table of contents for a Hebrew document (specifically, with Hebrew section and subsection names) I'm writing in LyX. When I try to compile my file I get a lot of error messages in form of

> `...C {\hebvav }\IeC {\hebtav }}{\@@number {2}} 
>   Your command was ignored. Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to continue without it.`

I'm using systems encoding (which did no problems without the TOC). How can I get rid of these annoying problems?

**EDIT:** Here is [example of the code](http://pastebin.com/hKB2HF9g) (in this specific there are two of this type but in the full there are around twenty):

% Preview source code

```
%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{Dark}{gray}{.2} 
\definecolor{Medium}{gray}{.6} 
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.8} 
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
\date{ }
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\centering
\vspace*{0.08\textheight}
{\Huge\bfseries Assisting Material }\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Course}\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Lecturer:}\\[\baselineskip] 
{\large\scshape Prof. }\par
\vfill  {\plogo}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\scshape Concluded by Coargo,2013}\par 
\vspace*{0.16\textheight}  
\endgroup


\tableofcontents{}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}%

\title{נוסחאון }

\maketitle

\part{הסתברות}


\section*{{\beginL 1\endL}. הסתברות בדידה - \L{$\text{Discrete Probability}$}}


\section*{{\beginL 2\endL}. משתנים מקרים בדידים}


\paragraph*{הגדרות ומונחים:}
\begin{itemize}
\item מ\char`\"{}מ \L{$X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$}
\item הסתברות למאורע \L{$P(X=x)=P(A_{x})={\displaystyle \sum_{\omega:X(\omega)=x}P(\omega)}$}. 
\end{itemize}

\paragraph*{משפטים והערות}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \L{$Var(X)=\mathbb{E[}[X^{2}]-\mathbb{E}[X]^{2}$}. 
\item \L{$\text{Law of Repeated Expectation/Partition Theorm}$}: \L{$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]=\mathbb{E}[X]$}. 
\end{enumerate}

\section*{{\beginL 3\endL}.מרחבי הסתברות כללים ומשתנים מקרים רציפים}


\paragraph*{מרחבי הסתברות כללים}

בנוסחאון זה בחר המחבר לא להכניס דברים יסודיים עליהם היה סבור לא ינתנו
שאלות במבחן, דוגמת הגדרת מרחב מדגם,מידת הסתברות, אלגברת בורל וכד'.
למעוניין בהרחבת אופקים הנושא נידון בהרחבה יתרה בקלסר. 


\paragraph*{משתנה מקרי רציף}


\subparagraph*{\uline{הגדרות:}}
\begin{itemize}
\item משתנה מקרי רציף הוא \L{$X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$}כך ש\L{$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:X^{-1}((-\infty,x])\in\mathcal{F}$}. 
\end{itemize}

\subparagraph*{\uline{משפטים והערות}}


\paragraph*{תכונות ה\L{$cdf,pdf$}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item תכונות של \L{$F(x)$}:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \L{$x\ge y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge f(y)$}.
\item \L{$ $}\L{${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0}$}
\item \L{$ $}\L{${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1}$}
\item \L{$F$}רציפה מימין אך איננה רציפה משמאל )ואם כן אזי \L{$P(X=x)=0$}(
\end{enumerate}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\item \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** and the lyx file [itself](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4h0mo7jbp6840z/mckup.lyx):

Comment: You posted `LaTeX` code. If you want a purely `LaTeX` answer, that is the right thing to do. If you are looking for a `LyX` answer, you should post a `.lyx` file (in addition).

Comment: In your exported .tex file, does replacing `\usepackage{babel}` with `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}` solve the problem? I get the following pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3hj8m6079dq7s5/mckup.pdf

Comment: Really strange... In my files I found this line doesn't exist. I tried including in the preamble manually in LyX but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is the pdf correct? I unfortunately cannot read Hebrew. If it is correct, I will post the `.tex` code and LyX solution.

Comment: Almost. The toc is empty even though when I double clicked the TOC in LyX, it seemed like I do have chapters and sub-chapters. Thanks

Comment: OK, well I put it as an answer just to post the `.tex` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `.tex` code compiles to pdf:

```
%% LyX 2.1.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255,latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{Dark}{gray}{.2} 
\definecolor{Medium}{gray}{.6} 
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.8} 
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
\date{ }
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\makeatother

\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\centering
\vspace*{0.08\textheight}
{\Huge\bfseries Assisting Material }\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Course}\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape Lecturer:}\\[\baselineskip] 
{\large\scshape Prof. }\par
\vfill  {\plogo}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
{\scshape Concluded by Coargo,2013}\par 
\vspace*{0.16\textheight}  
\endgroup


\tableofcontents{}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}%
\inputencoding{cp1255}%

\title{ðåñçàåï }

\maketitle

\part{äñúáøåú}


\section*{{\beginL 1\endL}. äñúáøåú áãéãä - \L{$\text{Discrete Probability}$}}


\section*{{\beginL 2\endL}. îùúðéí î÷øéí áãéãéí}


\paragraph*{äâãøåú åîåðçéí:}
\begin{itemize}
\item î\char`\"{}î \L{$X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$}
\item äñúáøåú ìîàåøò \L{$P(X=x)=P(A_{x})={\displaystyle \sum_{\omega:X(\omega)=x}P(\omega)}$}. 
\end{itemize}

\paragraph*{îùôèéí åäòøåú}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \L{$Var(X)=\mathbb{E[}[X^{2}]-\mathbb{E}[X]^{2}$}. 
\item \L{$\text{Law of Repeated Expectation/Partition Theorm}$}: \L{$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]=\mathbb{E}[X]$}. 
\end{enumerate}

\section*{{\beginL 3\endL}.îøçáé äñúáøåú ëììéí åîùúðéí î÷øéí øöéôéí}


\paragraph*{îøçáé äñúáøåú ëììéí}

áðåñçàåï æä áçø äîçáø ìà ìäëðéñ ãáøéí éñåãééí òìéäí äéä ñáåø ìà éðúðå
ùàìåú áîáçï, ãåâîú äâãøú îøçá îãâí,îéãú äñúáøåú, àìâáøú áåøì åëã'.
ìîòåðééï áäøçáú àåô÷éí äðåùà ðéãåï áäøçáä éúøä á÷ìñø. 


\paragraph*{îùúðä î÷øé øöéó}


\subparagraph*{\uline{äâãøåú:}}
\begin{itemize}
\item îùúðä î÷øé øöéó äåà \L{$X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$}ëê ù\L{$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:X^{-1}((-\infty,x])\in\mathcal{F}$}. 
\end{itemize}

\subparagraph*{\uline{îùôèéí åäòøåú}}


\paragraph*{úëåðåú ä\L{$cdf,pdf$}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item úëåðåú ùì \L{$F(x)$}:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \L{$x\ge y\Rightarrow f(x)\ge f(y)$}.
\item \L{$ $}\inputencoding{latin9}\L{${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0}$}
\item \inputencoding{cp1255}\L{$ $}\inputencoding{latin9}\L{${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1}$}
\item \inputencoding{cp1255}\L{$F$}øöéôä îéîéï àê àéððä øöéôä îùîàì )åàí
ëï àæé \L{$P(X=x)=0$}(
\end{enumerate}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\item \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As far as the LyX solution, all I had to do was export to `LaTeX (pdflatex)` and change `\usepackage{babel}` to `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}`. the reason our exported `.tex` files were different is because of our versions. I'm using LyX 2.1 beta 1. You can download it here:
ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta1

If you happen to use Ubuntu, installing 2.1.0dev is even easier. See:
http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3

EDIT:
here is a `LyX` solution that works for me. We have different operating systems and different TeX distributions (e.g. different versions of the babel package) so it's possible it will not work for you.

1. Go to Document > Settings > Preamble and add the following:

   `\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}`
2. Go to Document > Settings > Local Layout and put the following:

   `Provides babel 1`
3. Click on "Validate" and then on "OK".

Your `LyX` file should compile.

Comment: Seems really strange but I totally forgot how to switch between tex and lyx (I know i posted latex code but can't remember how I did so). How can I do it? side-question: why do you use lyx 2.1dev? which advantage it has?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis File > Export. I use `LyX 2.1dev` mainly because I'm a `LyX` developer. Besides many bug fixes, there are many new features: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX21

Comment: thanks but how can I add `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}` to my original lyx (from which I took the mock up)?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I did not make any other edits to the original `.lyx` file that you posted. All I did was export it, make the change, and run `pdflatex`.

Comment: But I can't export lyx file if i have errors in it,can I?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis The errors are not from `LyX`, they are from `pdflatex`. So you can just export from `LyX`, make the modification, and then run `pdflatex`. If this works, then we can look at automating this.

Comment: I'm a total newbie so sorry for these annoying questions. To which extension should I export the file before changing it and what do you mean by running pdflatex? returning to lyx with the modified file and then running lyx?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis What OS are you using? Did you install LyX 2.1beta or not?

Comment: Windows 7, haven't installed it yet but still downloading.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis After it downloads, export and run pdflatex. MiKTeX probably installs a program to do this (so just click on the .tex file to open that program). If not, run from the command window.

Comment: In which extension, I need to export the file?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex)

Comment: I did it. then I opened the file in TeXWork added `hebrew` and what's next? should be noticed that in the TeXWorK i see question marks instead of hebrew and when I tried importing it back to lyx it made me a corrupted gibberish non-hebrew document

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I do not know how this works on Windows. Can you please post the exported `.tex` file so that I can make sure it is the same as mine?

Comment: here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/68ydvasp2vx3uf4/mckup%20%281%29.tex thanks again.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis strange. That's what you get when you export the `.lyx` file that you posted before? It looks like you changed other things... And when you compile you get those question marks in the pdf?

Comment: I changed nothing (the source code was pasted by another user so maybe he fixed some of my errors). and yes. Even when changing encoding to windows-1255 the TOC left with the question marks.

Comment: It's strange that our files are different. This should not happen. But I will look into it. I will try to make an in-`LyX` solution that works for me and we will just have to hope it works for you. If not, I'll be out of ideas.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis see my edit (after "EDIT"). Does it work?

Comment: no. I get same error. sorry :(

Comment: One last try. Download this LyX file and try to compile it (without editing): https://www.dropbox.com/s/lltg8drnkd434ga/mckup.lyx

Comment: Now it compiles. thanks. A few more nuisances: 
a. the TOC shows only the name of chapter and not the paragraphs. should it happen (I want the TOC to include every paragraph)?
b. Why this file compiles and mine didn't ?
Thanks again.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis look at Document Settings > Numbering & TOC. It sounds to me that you want "paragraph" to be "yes". Move the slider accordingly.

Comment: I moved the slider but still I only see the name of part and not of the paragraphs. Seems like my LyX decided ruining my document in any price.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis I'm not sure what's going on. I think that support for Hebrew (in LyX and in LaTeX packages) is unfortunately not very advanced yet.

Comment: now its my fault. I used regular `*paragraph`s and other stars. Oh, now i feel really lame. Suppose I have another file with same problem (the one from where I took this mock up), I just need to take the preamble and layout from this document, compile in lyx 2.1 and it will work fine?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis That should be the plan, but I would not be surprised if something goes wrong. `LaTeX` and `beamer` are fragile (for good reasons) in my opinion and adding `LyX` on top of that can complicate things even more. But yes, that's what you should try. You should also take a look at the `LyX` manuals in the Help menu. Go through the `Introduction` and the `Tutorial`. Also, if you feel like contributing to the Hebrew translations for LyX (either the commands or the documentation), please let me know. Finally, consider emailing `lyx-users@lists.lyx.org` for future questions.

Comment: it worked great. thanks again. what do you mean by translation of commands and documentation? As well as I know version 2.0.6 seems translated quite well (version 2.1 naturally is still a little bit laggy hence I can't judge it).

Comment: @CoarguAliquis That's good to know. Well if something comes up, let me know at skostysh@lyx.org.